# issue with equating dictionaries and global issue

Tags: python-3.x, equality, defaultdict

Trying to figure best way to union of two dictionaries. Here is the code that I have. Counter is one of the options that I found.

```
    def __add__(self,right):
        mergedbag = Bag()
        mergedbag.bag_value = copy.copy(self.bag_value)
        for item in right.bag_value.keys():
            mergedbag.bag_value[item] += right.bag_value[item]
        return mergedbag
```

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware of this: Python already has a `Bag` type object, in the form of [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I did try that but it did't work either.

Comment: What do you mean by *didn't work*? `Counter(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d']) == Counter(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])` is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if two dictionaries have the same contents, simply use an equality test:

```
self.bag_items == bag_equal.bag_items
```

Python does this comparison test efficiently; keys and values have to match exactly and difference in length means the dictionaries are not equal:

```
>>> a = {'a': 'b'}
>>> b = {'a': 'b'}
>>> a == b
True
>>> b['b'] = 'c'
>>> a == b
False
>>> del b['b']
>>> b['a'] = 'c'
>>> a == b
False
>>> b['a'] = 'b'
>>> a == b
True
```

Note that rather than raise a `TypeError`, `__eq__` should return the `NotImplemented` sentinel object to signal that equality testing is not supported:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Bag):
        return NotImplemented
   return self.bag_items == other.bag_items
```

As a side-note, the `in` membership operator already returns either `True` or `False`, there is no need to use a conditional expression in `__contains__`; the following is enough:

```
def __contains__(self, include):
    return include in self.bag_items
```

Your code never actually does anything with the `items` passed in however, nor are you ever counting the items. Your `count()` method should just look up the element in `self.bag_items` and return the count once you properly track counts.

Comment: I made the changes to the method in the class, but its still giving True. I think its because it's not taking into account that each item in the dictionary has to be of exact same count as well. Dictionary b and c are exactly the same in terms of their items and their count as well (same no. of a's ,b's, c's and d's) so the result should be true..however since the count is not same in dictionary b and d (d has one extra 'a') it should return False.

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS: you are not doing anything with `items` in the `__init__` method, so your `bag_items` is  always empty. Empty dictionaries are always equal to other empty dictionaries.

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS: I focused only on your specific question; fixing everything about your Bag item would make my answer too long and verbose, but as written, your Bag requires a lot of work to actually fit the definition of a bag type.

Comment: I made changes in the `__init__` method. I'll give it another try. Thanks for all the input.